# Simulating Heading in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, simulator, gpx

Is it possible to simulate heading in Xcode? My iOS project tracks the user location and heading while driving. But I cannot test it in simulator because simulator is unable to track heading (no compass hardware).

It is very inconvenient to go out in the field with actual device for each testing session.

I was thinking on the lines of getting a sample GPX file. Do you think GPX file will contain heading information and simulator will be able to use it?

Comment: Looking for something like this as well. I see a `degreesType` here: http://www.topografix.com/gpx/1/1/gpx.xsd

Comment: Just tried it - I got locations working with a gpx file, and I tried adding a magvar tag with degreesType content in my wpt tags, but these values did not get set on the CLLocation course.